# CuDNNLSTM: Failed to call ThenRnnForward

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, gpu, lstm

I am facing an issue when trying to use CuDNNLSTM instead of keras.layers.LSTM.

This is the error I am getting:

> Failed to call ThenRnnForward with model config: [rnn_mode,
> rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 2, 0, 0 , [num_layers,
> input_size, num_units, dir_count, seq_length, batch_size]: [1, 300,
> 512, 1, 5521, 128]     [[{{node bidirectional_1/CudnnRNN_1}} =
> CudnnRNN[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@train...NNBackprop"],
> direction="unidirectional", dropout=0, input_mode="linear_input",
> is_training=true, rnn_mode="lstm", seed=87654321, seed2=0,
> _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](bidirectional_1/transpose_1,
> bidirectional_1/ExpandDims_1, bidirectional_1/ExpandDims_1,
> bidirectional_1/concat_1)]]    [[{{node loss/mul/_75}} =
> _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
> send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
> send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1209_loss/mul",
> tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
> _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Also, I got this error in one of the runs:

> InternalError: GPU sync failed

And the kernel kept dying after each run.

I only started getting this error when I tried to run it on a VM instance on google cloud with CuDNNLSTM.

my code is:

```
MAX_LEN = max(len(article) for article in X_train_tokens)
EMBEDDING_DIM=300
vocab_size = len(word_to_id)
classes = 2 
# Text input
text_input = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,))
embedding = Embedding(vocab_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=MAX_LEN)(text_input)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False))(embedding)
pred = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[text_input],outputs=pred)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop',     metrics=['accuracy'])
batch_size = 128
generator = text_training_generator(batch_size)
steps = len(X_train)/ batch_size 

model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=True, epochs=10)
```

The model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 5521)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 5521, 300)         8099100   
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 1024)              3330048   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 2050      
=================================================================
Total params: 11,431,198
Trainable params: 11,431,198
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably your are running out of memory on the gpu. Your network is very large with 11 million trainable parameters. Do you really need a 512*2 Output of your recurrent layer?

Furthermore your embedding_dim is also quite large, while your vocabulary is quite small with 5k words. I guess your network is too complex for your problem. I would suggest to try an embedding size of 32 and a LSTM size of 32 as a start. If your accuracy is still bad, you can increase complexity.

```
EMBEDDING_DIM = 32
Bidirectional(LSTM(32, return_sequences=False))(embedding)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error but only for `predict`. For training it works fine. How is that possible?

Comment: Do you load the model again or do you use the model already loaded in memory?

Comment: I use the model already loaded in memory because of this other issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724821/keras-custom-metric-sum-is-wrong, but I do reload the weights with `load_weights`.

Comment: I guess it's the weights reloading, but sounds a bit weird

Comment: I got this error with 128 units for a bidirectional lstm on an nvidia tesla t4 with 16gigs of memory. can it be possible that memory outage is the issue in my case too?

Comment: @NaveenReddyMarthala What happens if you reduce it to 16?

Comment: reducing the num of units to 64 worked fine for me.

Answer (score 13):

I was facing this issue too with my model and Tensorflow 2.4.1 recently; I have also found out it is reproducible with e.g. the model from the tutorial [Text generation with an RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation). Running on the CPU (and consuming ~3 GB RAM), training fails on the GPU with 8 GB memory with the error

```
2021-02-12 18:45:48.482327: E tensorflow/stream_executor/dnn.cc:616] CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1859): 'cudnnRNNForwardTraining( cudnn.handle(), rnn_desc.handle(), model_dims.max_seq_length, input_desc.handles(), input_data.opaque(), input_h_desc.handle(), input_h_data.opaque(), input_c_desc.handle(), input_c_data.opaque(), rnn_desc.params_handle(), params.opaque(), output_desc.handles(), output_data->opaque(), output_h_desc.handle(), output_h_data->opaque(), output_c_desc.handle(), output_c_data->opaque(), workspace.opaque(), workspace.size(), reserve_space.opaque(), reserve_space.size())'
2021-02-12 18:45:48.482405: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1763] OP_REQUIRES failed at cudnn_rnn_ops.cc:1521 : Internal: Failed to call ThenRnnForward with model config: [rnn_mode, rnn_input_mode, rnn_direction_mode]: 3, 0, 0 , [num_layers, input_size, num_units, dir_count, max_seq_length, batch_size, cell_num_units]: [1, 256, 1024, 1, 100, 32, 0]
```

I also observed the GPU memory filling up to the limit on `model.compile()` call before the error.

I solved that by prohibiting the full GPU memory allocation by adding

```
gpu_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU")
for device in gpu_devices:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, True)
```

early enough in the script (e.g. after `import tensorflow as tf`). This instructs Tensorflow to allocate GPU memory on demand. With that, training runs on GPU, only consuming ~2.2 GB memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just try reducing the batch size to 16.